# Complex Full text search using PlayFramework Search / Hibernate Search

Tags: hibernate, lucene, playframework, hibernate-search

Suppose there are only two type of model objects.

Tag
Article

Article can have a variable number of tags, as well as a large text field containing the body of the article.

How do I perform an efficient full text search for articles matching a set of tags that I define? For example, out of 1 million articles, what's the best way to efficiently query (with count and pagination support) for articles that 1) match body:business* and 2) are tag with "America", "Economy" and NOT tagged with "Asia"?

I am able to efficiently do 1) (using HQL or plain old SQL) and 2) (Using lucene query) separately, but not both of them together. Anybody got some ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you mean by "both of them together"... SQL DB search and lucene query are 2 different mechanisms using different indexing data so they work differently and return different results. What do you mean by using them together?

Comment: As in, I want to filter articles that are both tagged with America (which is something that has to be done in the database) and articles which contains the world "business" (which should be done in the search engine). I could separately find articles using each methods and then take intersection of the results, but that seems like a really inefficient approach. By using them together I meant if there was some way to implement this more efficiently than intersecting the results.

Comment: Yes, it's not quite easy to realize the intersection and it wouldn't take into account the pertinence of both sets of results. If there is a way to mix both, I don't know :)... The only way I know is to store all search information in one single indexing engine and there is nothing against indexing some DB data with lucene for example as it has been created for that. Thus, you could search for everything using lucene (or another engine such as elastic search)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at the [Elastic Search](http://geeks.aretotally.in/play-framework-module-elastic-search-distributed-searching-with-json-http-rest-or-java) module? It is a very powerful module, and the module owner has done a lot of work documenting his work.